# Encountered symbol "DROP" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle

Hi I am writing a simple set of oracle statements but I am getting an error saying "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol DROP when expecting one of the following". I am not sure what is wrong with my statements. Any help is appreciated.

```
DECLARE
table_exists number := 0;  
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO table_exists FROM dba_tables WHERE owner = 'ABC' 
AND table_name = 'XYZ';
   If (table_exists = 1) then     
      DROP TABLE "ABC"."XYZ";
    End If;
End;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want use DDL statements in PL/SQL blocks, you have to use dynamic SQL.
Try this:

```
execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ' || owner.table_name
```